# AppDomain event that gets called for *ATTEMPTED* assembly resolution

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assembly-loading

Is there an event that we can hook to, that gets called *BEFORE* an assembly is resolved.

For example if some code in the AppDomain is calling Assembly.Load(path) , the event will be raised, saying this assembly is attempted to be loaded?

This can be useful for redirecting possible assembly loads that are hardcoded in some components.

Doing this also from configuration is a valid option, if possible.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, from the documentation, that no event is thrown right at the start of this process.  Therefore, I suggest (if possible), that you write something like the following and use it through-out:

```
public static class AssemblyLoader
{
    public delegate void LoadDelegate(string path);

    public void LoadAssembly(string path)
    {
        if(OnPreLoad != null)
            OnPreLoad(path);
        // load assembly here
    }  // eo LoadAssembly

    public event LoadDelegate OnPreLoad;
} // eo AssemblyLoader
```

Then, you can use this method anywhere in your code when you want to load an assembly.

Obviously you might want to use a proper object here in that delegate (not just the path) to prevent loading of the assembly or do something different.

Comment: The problem i have, is that the assembly loading code is not written by me (3rd party). This code uses a hard-coded location to resolve plugins. I would like to intercept this process and be able to supply my own location, since it causes problems with distributing my application that uses this 3rd party.

Comment: @liortal, ah I wondered about that - indeed this method won't work if you're not in control of the process of loading assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such event.  One possible hack is to intentionally mis-configure the AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase property so that the CLR can never find any of the assemblies.  In which case the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event will be fired, allowing you to implement you own assembly resolution scheme.